# Axon Framework salta error al momento de registrar en el Axon Server: ForbiddenClassException

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring, eventos, spring-mvc

Estoy utilizando

**Java** 19
**Spring Boot:** 2.7.5   **Axon Framework**: 4.6.2  **Axon Server**: 4.6.7

Al momento de enviar un post para registrar un usuario; veo que ingresa hasta la capa de servicio y al intentar publicar el evento en el Axon Server (Event Store) con el **comando**: **"commandGateway.sendAndWait"**(objeto) salta inmediantamente el siguiente error:

**Clase de la capa de servicio que publica mediante el comando: commandGateway.sendAndWait en Axon Server**

```
@Component
public class UsuarioApplicationService {
private final CommandGateway commandGateway;
private final RegisterUsuarioValidator registerUsuarioValidator;
private final EditUsuarioValidator editUsuarioValidator;

public UsuarioApplicationService(CommandGateway commandGateway, RegisterUsuarioValidator registerUsuarioValidator, EditUsuarioValidator editUsuarioValidator) {
    this.commandGateway = commandGateway;
    this.registerUsuarioValidator = registerUsuarioValidator;
    this.editUsuarioValidator = editUsuarioValidator;
}

public Result<RegisterUsuarioResponse, Notification> register(RegisterUsuarioRequest request) throws Exception {
    String usuarioId =  UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String createdBy = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    RegisterUsuario command = new RegisterUsuario(
        usuarioId,
        request.getNombre().trim(),
        request.getClave().trim(),
        createdBy
    );
    Notification notification = this.registerUsuarioValidator.validate(command);
    if (notification.hasErrors()) return Result.failure(notification);
    commandGateway.sendAndWait(command); //Aquí se cae (esta línea publica el evento en Axon Server)        
        
    RegisterUsuarioResponse registerUsuarioResponse = new RegisterUsuarioResponse(
        command.getId(),
        command.getNombre(),
        command.getClave()
    );
    return Result.success(registerUsuarioResponse);
}
```

**Clase RegisterUsuario**

```
package com.app.inventario.message.commands;

import lombok.Value;
import org.axonframework.modelling.command.TargetAggregateIdentifier;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@Value
public class RegisterUsuario {
@TargetAggregateIdentifier
private String id;
private String nombre;
private String clave; 
private String createdBy;
}
```

Luego de pasar la línea que contiene el comando mencionado; salta el siguiente error:

**Exception in thread "CommandProcessor-0" com.thoughtworks.xstream.security.ForbiddenClassException: com.app.inventario.message.commands.RegisterUsuario**

Answer (score 0):

Falta declarar el método **XStream** en el archivo de configuración de Axon Framework.

AxonConfig.java //Archivo de configuración

```
@Bean
public XStream xStream() { //AGREGAR EL METODO XSTREM CON LA RUTA DE CARPETA SU PROYECTO. Ejemplo "com.app.inventario"
    XStream xStream = new XStream();
    xStream.allowTypesByWildcard(new String[] {
        "com.app.inventario.**"
    });
    return xStream;
}
```

También se debe agregar en archivo de main de spring boot lo siguiente:

```
package com.app.inventario.usuario;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import com.app.inventario.usuario.infrastructure.config.AxonConfig;

@SpringBootApplication
@Import({ AxonConfig.class }) //MUY IMPORTANTE AGREGAR PARA ENLAZAR CON AXON FRAMEWORK
public class ConfiguracionUsuarioApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ConfiguracionUsuarioApplication.class, args);
 }

}
```